# Issue with Rails developer tools when trying to install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nokogiri

I am getting the above error when trying to install Nokogiri.

I believe this issue is related to x-code and/or rvm. My thought is that I need to uninstall and reinstall either one or both to get this to work.

My question is based on the error below you believe I need to uninstall and reinstall xcode and/or rvm to solve this problem? Is there something else you would try first?

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the error I get

```
$gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160201-5728-joih4p.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

/Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:621:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:336:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jackburum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having this problem, I solved it simply by opening from my local comp applications > xcode and agreeing to the new terms. Then I ran bundle and my app began working.